# Number counts up before using an if statement to pause?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want the number to stop when the variable `num` reaches a whole number. The pausing works correctly, but it goes up by 0.01 then pauses. The statement is ran every frame (via `requestAnimationFrame`).

```
if (Math.floor(num * 100) / 100 == Math.floor(num) && pause < 50) {
        pause += 1;
    } else {
        pause = 0;
        num += 0.01;
}
```

The complete code block is on GitHub:
https://github.com/BootLegAidan/Geometrical-Thing/blob/master/Update.js

Comment: Are you sure the extra 0.01 isn't from the previous execution?

Comment: I don't think it is. But if it is, would you know how to fix it?

Comment: You'd need a higher multiple to check `num` against. Instead of 100, try 100000 or 1000000.

Comment: That works, but it only starts working after num hits 20. Even if I checked it against 1000. The way I need it is so it starts at 2

Comment: This does not appear to be complete code. The loop that this happens in is not included.

Comment: [Heres the complete code](https://github.com/BootLegAidan/Geometrical-Thing/blob/master/Update.js) @TylerN

Comment: Is it due to the nature of `requestAnimationFrame()`? "requests that the browser calls a specified function to update an animation **before** the next repaint." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @Aidan If you replace `0.01` with `0.1` then everything works as expected, I believe this is an issue with JavaScript's handling of floating points, not an issue with the if statement or loop. You need a way to get nicer floating points.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be your `Math.floor(num * 100 ) / 100 == Math.floor(num)` condition evaluating to `true` even if `num` has a very small decimal value -- such as 1.000000007.

You can avoid that issue by comparing `num` to its rounded value directly:

```
if (num == Math.floor(num) && pause < 50) {
```

Compared that way, unless `num` is a whole number, the condition won't be `true`.

Comment: When you add a decimal, the number gets a tiny bit higher than the value actually should be. so if you had `num += 0.01`, `num` would actually increment by 0.010...01

Comment: What is `num` to start? When is it changed outside of that loop?